# conditional unique constraint on postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to basically enforce a unique constraint on postgresql schema and I have already used a partial index as below:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX emails_email_key ON emails (email) WHERE verified = 'true'
```

While this works in general for validating the existence of single verified e-mail, my concern is can I create a database constraint so that if a record with `a@example.com` e-mail and `verified` set to `true` already exists, we can just disallow any new record with `email` set to `a@example.com` regardless of value of `verified` column. In the constraint I've created, we can insert new record with e-mail `a@example.com` and `verified` set to `false` which is not as big deal on the insertion and e-mail verification process itself but I'll have to handle few more cases on application level that I wish I could offload to database constraint itself.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How is what you're asking for different than a unique constraint on `email`?  If you want to leave any existing rows with `verified='false'`, you'd need another column to distinguish old (existing) values from new ones - do you have a creation date column?

Comment: I do have creation date column (& update date). How would you suggest to (ab)use that field? I think I can not just do it based on (email, verified='true').

Comment: Assuming that you can't just create the unique index without `where verified='true'` (because you have some duplicate email addresses you want to keep), you could disallow the creation of new duplicates (regardless of verification) by adding a column that is `1` for old rows and `NULL` for new rows, then make a unique index on the combination of that new column and `email`.  Since postgres considers NULLs distinct in a UNIQUE index (see http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html), this would allow any existing duplicates and prevent new ones.